# Php Laravel 404 routing

Tags: php, laravel

I have a problem with Laravel. I am working on an api, and every rout gives me 200. I want to create a 404 error page if the route does not exist in the routes/api.php

These are my routes:

```html
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function($request) {
    //Account management
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function ($request) {
        Route::post('/login', 'API\V1\AuthController@login');
        Route::post('/register', 'API\V1\AuthController@register');
        Route::get ('/logout', 'API\V1\AuthController@logout');
        Route::post('/reset', 'API\V1\AuthController@reset');
    });

    //AUTHENTICATED ROUTES
    Route::group(['middleware' => 'jwt'], function ($request) {

        //Api info
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'auth'], function ($request) {
            Route::get ('/appdata', 'API\V1\AuthController@appdata');
        });

        //Workouts
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'calls'], function ($request) {
            Route::get('/', 'API\V1\WorkoutController@viewAll');
            Route::get('/{workout_id}', 'API\V1\WorkoutController@get');
        });

        //Products
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'products'], function ($request) {
            Route::get('/', 'API\V1\ProductController@viewAll');
            Route::get('/{product_id}', 'API\V1\ProductController@get');
            //Route::post('/add', 'API\V1\ProductController@add');
        });

        //Users
        Route::group(['prefix' => 'users'], function ($request) {
            Route::get('/', 'API\V1\UserController@getUsers');
            Route::get('/{id}/', 'API\V1\UserController@getById');
        });

    });

});
```

For example if I go to: localhost:/abc -> I want to load a 404 error page.

Thank you!

Comment: What does it currently return when you hit `localhost/abc` ? By default it would return 404 for anything that doesn't have a route defined, you must have defined it somewhere.

Comment: If I go to that route I get 200. I can go to any route I want and still get 200.

Comment: Is that file your main routes.php?

Comment: I have 2 files: one for the api and one for the web pages, located at: routes/web.php and routes/api.php, The code i have added the the question is from api.php

Comment: Show us the main one too, also are you connect through nginx or working on local dev env? Paste that config too.

Comment: <?php

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143711/discussion-between-rare-urs-and-matt-the-ninja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `handler.php` and include following in `handle()` method

```
if($e instanceof NotFoundException) {
    return view('notFoundView');
}
```

Comment: Where this class

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to fix it. in web.php and api.php I had to add the following line.

```html
Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) {

    return view('errors');

})->where('any', '.*');
```

Now everytime a route is not matched, I get a custom error page(404 and 500).